# Only 1 orWhere in Bookshelf query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

I have the following `Bookshelf` method in my controller:

```
const transaction = await Transaction.query({
    where: { status: "paid", id: req.params.transaction_id },
    orWhere: { status: "settled", id: req.params.transaction_id },
    orWhere: { status: "PERFORMED", id: req.params.transaction_id },
}).fetch();
```

However, it doesn't seem to apply the second `orWhere` and only returns instances where the status matches "paid" or "settled". Is it perhaps not allowed to use a second `orWhere` in the query? What would be a better syntax?

Comment: keys in objects are unique.  you can't repeat them

Comment: Ah, of course, that explains it. Any idea how I then should do this in Bookshelf instead?

Comment: Gonna have to wait for someone who knows about Bookshelf to answer that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query callback:

```
Transaction.query(function (qb) {
    qb.where('key1', 'value1')
       .orWhere('key2', 'value2')
       .orWhere('key3', 'value3')
       .orWhere('key4', 'value4')
});
```